# model.addAttribute (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит 
model.addAttribute("some text", someObject);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ваш шаблонизатор вы передаете model в которой  находятся данные необходимые для отображения на веб-страничке. `model.addAttribute("some text", someObject);` это добавление в передаваемую модель данных, в вашем случае `someObject`, которые потом будут доступны по ключу который вы указываете как параметр String, в вашем случае это `"some text"`